# Unable to access public JavaScript object var

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a class that starts like this:

```
function event()
{
    this.event_id = null;
```

and then it all gets populated with an init function.

In another part of my script I can not access these variables.

If I run this code:

```
    console.log(my_event);
    console.log(my_event.event_id);
```

For the first line the console gives me a nice representation of the event object with the event_id populated, but for the second line it gives me null.

What's going on?  The variable should be public right?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You set it to null, what did you expect?

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code. Preferably a complete test case that you think should work. Preferably duplicated on jsfiddle.

Comment: There is no distinction of public and private, any object property is public. And `null` is the expected value, because you have set it to that.

Comment: please a more understandable code.. because we don't know if you already populated the `my_event` with the function object

Comment: It gets populated before I try to access it using the console and this value is shown when I do console.log(my_event);

Comment: @JonnyWhite if it's shown with that, then you populate it asynchronously. The logged object only looks at the state when you expand it in console, not at the time of logging. You have left out the key to the puzzle, which is the code of how you populate it.

Comment: @Esailija Thank you.  That's what was confusing me.  I thought they were both from the time of logging.  Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `console.log` a non-scalar value, such as an object, its actual state is retrieved only at the time when you expand to see the object properties in chrome developer tools console. Short arrays or array-likes of < 100 items will automatically expand though the state is usually (my test results have varied on this, maybe I'm just seeing things) not immediately retrieved in that case either.

So if you get `null` from `console.log(my_event.event_id);`, then it was in fact `null` at the time that `console.log` executed. The results of `console.log(my_event);` depend on when you expand the logged object in console. If you made an ajax request that modifies the `event_id` property and the request was completed by the time you expanded the object in console, it will show the changed value.

Also, every object property in javascript is "public".